# TableLayoutPanel isn't showing padding on bottom when scrollbar is visible

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to build "dashboard" like layout for my WinForms application.
I was able to build simple concept using TableLayoutPanel.
I'm able to add columns, rows and controls to tlp (TableLayoutPanel), but I get unwanted behaviour:
[image]

I have padding set to 5 on tlp, but after adding two rows that padding disappears - I can scroll to bottom, but I'd like that padding to be visible when scrollbar is at bottom.

I'm adding new row with this code:

```
private void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count - 1;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Insert(x,new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute,100));
    var b = new Button
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Text = "New"+x.ToString(),
        UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
    };
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
    x = tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count - 2;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b,0,x);
}
```

Is this behaviour by design or can I change it? Basically I'd like that bottom padding to be visible when I scroll to bottom on tlp.

As requested this is my tlp design code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.button5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // tableLayoutPanel1
    // 
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollMargin = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 10);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button1, 0, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button2, 1, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 100F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(459, 221);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // button1 - button in top left cell in tlp
    // 
    this.button1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 8);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(218, 94);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "button1";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // button2 - button in top right cell in tlp
    // 
    this.button2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(232, 8);
    this.button2.Name = "button2";
    this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(219, 94);
    this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
    this.button2.Text = "button2";
    this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // button5 - "Test" button
    // 
    this.button5.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
    this.button5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 427);
    this.button5.Name = "button5";
    this.button5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button5.TabIndex = 1;
    this.button5.Text = "Test";
    this.button5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button5_Click);
    // 
    // Form2
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(755, 462);
    this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
    this.Controls.Add(this.button5);
    this.Name = "Form2";
    this.Text = "Form2";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form2_Load);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

At first I have 2 rows, first set to 100 pixels absolute size, second to autofill, when I click "Test" button I'm inserting row that has same properties as first (absolute size, 100 px height)

Comment: Can you show the designer code for you `TableLayoutPanel` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce. It works just fine here. Do note that the distances are the Buttons' Margins, though. Does your TLP have AutoScroll on?

Comment: @user3185569 I've added my designer code

Comment: Ah. You should set AutoScrollMargin to 0 !

Comment: @TaW I've updated my question with designer code. I have AutoScroll set to True, Padding on TLP us set to 5px

Comment: @TaW I've changed AutoScrollMargin to 0, but have same behaviour - I can scroll to bottom, but there is no padding.

Comment: Hm, I made the difference here; but then I reverted it and now it doesn't work any longer.. I hate TLP

Comment: It seems you have 2 buttons added to the form using designer and then 2 more buttons using code-behind. There should be a difference between those and this is why you see that effect. My guess it's `tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Insert(x,new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute,100));` line, you shouldn't create a **new** style, try to reuse existing one. Or simply expect added buttons (and `TableLayoutPanel` members) closely before and after adding first button. You are looking for *differences*. Another "idea" is to add all of buttons in code-behind. Then you will see steady behavior.

Comment: @Sinatr I've changed my code and I'm adding all buttons in code-behind, but I get exactly same results. What I'm trying to get is that padding on bottom when scrollbar is visible. I'm able to add as many rows as I want, but when I have scrollbar then that bottom padding isn't included in scrollable region.

Comment: Or maybe opposite, it's there, but `ScrollBar` doesn't take it into account. Try to host `TableLayoutPanel` (disable scrollbars) inside `Panel` (enable scrollbars) and see what will happens.

Comment: For this workaround set AutoSize= true, I'd say..

Comment: You are using a TableLayoutPanel to mimic a FlowLayoutPanel — just use a FlowLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: @LarsTech thank's for suggestion, but FlowLayoutPanel won't work for me. I need option to resize items (be able to set that specific item takes 2 rows and 1 column), be able to move items (reorder them) and I need that table layout (rows and columns). I've created simple demo for this question, but in final solution button is replaced by custom controls.

Comment: @Sinatr I've tried that, but instead of panel I used UserControl (as this will eventually be turned into user control), after setting AutoScroll to true on my control everything works just as expected. Please post this as an answer and I'll gladly mark is as correct. Thank You!

Comment: I am glad it works. You can [post answer yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for future visitors having same problem.

Comment: @Sinatr I already did that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Sinatr and @TaW I've solved my problem.

[image]

As You may see after adding more rows and scrolling to bottom padding is still visible (desirable effect).

The key was to put TableLayoutPanel inside UserControl.

Here are properties that must be set:

TableLayoutPanel (inside UserControl):

- Dock:Top
- AutoSize:True
- AutoScroll:False

UserControl:

- AutoScroll:True

Below is designer code from my UserControl:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // tableLayoutPanel1
    // 
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 3;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.34F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(443, 10);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 1;
    // 
    // Dashboard
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.AutoScroll = true;
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
    this.Name = "Dashboard";
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(443, 208);
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Dashboard_Load);
    this.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Dashboard_MouseEnter);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();
}
```

I hope this help anyone having same problem.